# Apache Beam GroupByKey doesn't seem to output anything

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I have a Beam Pipeline running on Google Dataflow that takes inputs from Pubsub and Groups them by Key before processing the time-series data. Somehow when I run the pipeline, the code seems unable to process the GroupByKey step and the rest of the steps don't get run. (See attached screenshot for console output at the Group By Key step)

```
Window<KV<String, Data>> window = Window.<KV<String, Data>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(1)))
    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(pastEndOfWindow()))
    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(10))
    .discardingFiredPanes();

PCollection<KV<String, List<Data>>> keyToDataList = data.apply("Add Event Timestamp", WithTimestamps.of(new EventTimestampFunction()))
    .apply("Windowing", window)
    .apply("Group by Key", GroupByKey.create())
    .apply("Sort by date", ParDo.of(new SortDataFn()));
```

The strange thing is that the code used to work in the past but while testing out some small part modified downstream, the GroupByKey didn't work anymore. The worst thing was that reverting to the previous git version also didn't work. I tried cleaning the build, copying out the previous working files out into a new folder and they all didn't work. I'm tearing out my hair now so if anyone has some insights into this issue I'd really appreciate if you could help! Thanks in advance!!

[image: console output]

Comment: I guess that may depend completely on te window. If the watermark hasn't gone beyond any window, it is a very likely candidate. GBK needs to wait for the window to aggregate all data before firing... Does it make sense?

Comment: But some of the tests I've run have been ongoing for 8-10 hours, and most likely the watermark has already passed. Anyway the other jobs I've run in the past could work, it seems like some kind of build issue or when the job is being transferred to Dataflow something got messed up.

Comment: I think your best bet is to write some unit tests for your pipeline, specifically using [TestStreams](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2016/10/20/test-stream.html) and that way you can be sure if it is on your code or you can look somewhere else.

Comment: The strange thing is that I took the original files, ran it on Linux machine, and it worked. But doing it on my Windows machine is where the GroupByKey step got stuck. Does it sound like some kind of local build process issue? How can I reset the libraries/ build environment or pinpoint the source of the issue? I already did a mvn clean package so I thought the libraries should be re-downloaded. Asking this because at other times I've tried the other way round and the Linux deployed a stuck pipeline at the GroupBykey step... Sigh.. this is frustrating.. :(

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help here... but sounds really annoying indeed. Can't you just use Linux itself?

Comment: I've tried before having a stuck pipeline using Linux as well so even if it could work for the original job, it might not work on the new code. I have unit tests for the logic processing after GroupByKey and all, but not sure how to debug that particular step. I'm probably out of depth here and should probably change to using other tools to achieve the same end, thanks anyway for the suggestions @Carlos!

Comment: That's strange. 1. Could you state which Beam version you are using? 2. And to remove your old packages in maven you need to go to your .m2 folder and delete all the packages downloaded. 3. Also could you increase the allowed lateness to maybe an hour and see if that makes a difference? 4. At the same time if you could run `data.apply(TextIO.to("somewhere"))` to see that the data is being vetted for. 5. What key are you grouping by?

Comment: I found out sometime ago that the issue seems to stem from the fact that there wasn't enough data in the pipeline. During my testing I was publishing data to the pubsub topic something like once every 5 minutes. It worked once I increased the volume of data. ~shrug~

Comment: I'm having this issue today. Beam 2.20.0. PubSubIO.readStrings() at the beginning with a fixed window after. Nothing seems to be output by the GroupByKey I have. Going to try increasing the volume of data, but that's a bit weird because I want to use this for a low data volume use case.